# Postman-Newman: Run each request in collection in parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parallel-processing, postman-collection-runner, postman-newman

I need to create a huge data and for that I need to send a request 2000 times and in response it will give me back the `id` then using the `id` I need to run another collection using a file containing 100 records.
I know newman can run a particular collection in parallel but I'm not sure how I could set it up for my particular use case. Any ideas?

I tried to use `postman.setNextRequest` but it doesn't accept input files. What I want is I run the request and using the `id` from response I need to run entire collection using datafile. Also, I need that next request run shouldn't wait for earlier request to be finished. As soon as it gets `id` from the response it should run the collection and move on to the next interation.

Comment: Why not create a php/python/java/whatever script do do that for you?

Comment: @Martijn that's the best solution but I needed to do it quickly and was not well versed to create the script myself.